# Fate/stay night visual novel playing order

Tags: fate-stay-night, visual-novel-production

Why is it recommended to play Fate before UBW and Heaven's Feel (**Fate → UBW → Heaven's Feel**)

Since the Realta Nua version switches routes based on our choices, is it still recommended to play the VN in the recommended order (i.e. **Fate → UBW → Heaven's Feel**), or is it fine to play **UBW before Fate** (i.e. based on our choices)?

I know this is a general question, but while reading the other answers based on the order of the visual novel, most of them preferred the recommended order but did not give reasoning on why to follow the order.

Comment: While I still haven't actually played *Fate/Stay Night*, I'm fairly certain that the VN is structured in such a way that you *have* to play them in that order, because the options to unlock the other routes are locked until you do. So it's less about there being a particular reason to, and more simply because you don't have a choice. I may be misremembering, though, and like I said, I haven't actually played it.

Comment: Unless you have a complete save state you cannot play UBW before you have cleared Fate and you cannot play Heaven's Feel before you have cleared UBW. The choices to get to those routes aren't available.

Comment: @Ocean Yeah, shouldn't have installed the 100% save file. Without it there wouldn't be any route switches. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In the original R18+ PC game, the route order was restricted, so the play order is enforced:

1. Fate
2. Unlimited Blade Works (complete Fate)
3. Heavens Feel (complete Unlimited Blade Works Good or True Ending)

There was also a way to enter the Unlimited Blade Works route without completing Fate from Day 4. However, it locks you into a Bad End for Unlimited Blade Works Day 5 and Bad Ends don't unlock routes.

Source: [Full Image of the Mirror-Moon.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDOLj.jpg)

Because Realta Nua PC is 3 separate games, each being each route, there is really no restriction. However, from my understanding, the plot is not changed, so some reveals such as characters and abilities are glossed over when they appear again in a new route e.g. Rider's identity is revealed in Fate but from my recollection is glossed over in Heaven's Feel because of the original assumption that the player had already completed Fate. Not to mention the impact of certain events in Heaven's Feel does not hold the same weight if it was played first.

While there is nothing stopping you from playing any order you want, my personal suggestion would be to follow the original game's enforced play order: **Fate > Unlimited Blade Works > Heaven's Feel**.

Comment: So, should I follow the flowchart for every choice I make while playing in order to not switch to other routes?

Comment: @sushi The route switches happen relatively early on I would advise against following the flowchart for a first playthrough because the bad ends do have content, it's not a simple "bad decision, die".

Comment: @Renari "the bad ends do have content" I can think of a few Bad Ends in Heaven's Feel that are sort of notorious for that.

Comment: @sushi if you're playing the Relta Nua PC release which comes as 3 games i don't think you can access the other routes in each game. if you've managed to get your hand on the original R18+ game, as Renari said the route changes happen early on. if you want to make sure you enter your desired route you only need to look up to Day 3 (look for SaberClear for Unlimited Blade Works or SakuraRoute for Heavens Feel)

Answer (score 3):

You should follow this order not only because it is not possible to deviate from it without a cleared save state, but also because each new route expands more upon the world and various characters.

UBW contains spoilers for Fate, but not the other way around.
Heaven's Feel contains spoilers for UBW and Fate, but not the other way around.

Comment: oh,,didn't knew it contained spoilers to other routes,,thank you.